# Cube root in elisp

Tags: math

How do I take cube roots in emacs lisp? I thought of using fractional exponents like `$8^{1/3} = 2$` but I didn't know how to write `y` as a fraction in `(expt x y)`

Comment: You could use `(expt 8 (/ 1.0 3))`. Be sure that you use a float in the fraction...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of ways:

```lisp
(expt 8 (/ 1.0 3.0)) ⇒ 2.0
```

Or, if you want symbolic results:

```lisp
(require 'calc-arith)
(calcFunc-pow 8 (calcFunc-inv 3)) ⇒ (float 2 0)
(calcFunc-pow 8 (calcFunc-inv (list 'x))) ⇒ (^ 8 (/ 1 (x)))
```

See also the `defmath` macro described in [chapter 17.5.1 Defining New Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/calc/Defining-Functions.html) of the Emacs Calc manual.

Comment: In the first example it suffices to pass one float so that the output will be a float. In other words, `(/ 1.0 3.0)` is equivalent to `(/ 1.0 3)` and `(/ 1 3.0)`.